# Building a program in Pycharm for Ubuntu. How can I do it so that Ubuntu automatically opens Pycharm and Starts the Python Program?

Tags: ubuntu, python, pycharm

First, I want Ubuntu to boot straight into the Desktop and automatically open Pycharm IDE. Then, I want it to automatically run the Pycharm Program left open or last worked on. Lastly, without me doing anything at all, I want the program to run itself until next boot up and the process starts over.

Comment: You may wish to [edit] your question clarify the behavior you are looking for. Unfortunately, as is, your description isn't very clear to me. What are the exact steps you want taken and in what order?

Comment: I am very sorry for not clarifying. I updated my question.

Comment: Not a problem. That is much more clear. Thank you. =) With that said, what have you tried so far to achieve this goal? That is, where are you running into issues?

Comment: It is mainly where I want to automatically open Pycharm (which I am sure is possible with some linux terminal commands) and then have Pycharm automatically run the program which I believe is based on what the IDE programmers have done.

Comment: Why do you want to run it _in PyCharm_?

Answer (score 0):

Redgar:

**First**, I think that you want open automatically PyCharm in your system every time you turn on it.

e.g: If I wanna do it with vscode (another IDE):

1. Found it path. You can do it, for example, with the which or type command:

```
$ -> type code
code is /usr/bin/code
$ -> which code
/usr/bin/code
```

2. Create a new file in .config/autostart/ of your home user with this syntax:

```
touch /home/yourHomeUser/.config/autostart/vscode.desktop
```

Change vscode with the name of your program.

3. Edit it. This file can have a lot of lines and directives, but it will work fine:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/code
Name=VsCode
```

Change Name for the name you want to set it and Exec with the path that the wichh or type command returns.

Everytime you login with the user you created this file, the program will start automatically.

**Second**, if you want to execute a python file every time you start a session. You have a lot of options, some more practicals than others.

1. You can use the autostart file too, and change Exec with something like it:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/python /home/path/your_script.py
```

2. You can use /etc/rc.local. This is not highly recommended 'cause it execute with root .
3. You can use init.

**Another methods**:

1. You can use an alias to execute a command with the terminal that call the script and executes it (it's not automatically and needs you to run by hand) but it can also works.
2. You can use a crontab.

I hope I have been helpful.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for this answer. Pycharm apparently doesn't support ANY kind of auto launch python programs when booted. I found an alternative. To actually boot directly into the python program. And auto run it from there. Again thank you so much for this answer.